# Как работает область видимости с++

Tags: c++

Как мне известно, компилятор языка с++ переводит код, понятный человеку в машинный. Допустим у нас имеется вот такой код:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){

    {
       int a = 1;
       std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }
    
    {
       int a = 2;
       std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }
    
    {
       int a = 3;
       std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Понятное дело, что что каждая переменная будет иметь разный адрес в памяти. Но как их имена будут записаны до выполнения этого кода самим компьютером. Какие имена им будут присвоены после компиляции, идентификаторы же у них одинаковые, но лежат они в разных блоках кода? Как в последствии компьютер их отличит?

Comment: Это зависит от компилятора. В типичном случае у них вовсе не будет имён — зачем они компилятору?

Comment: И совершенно не факт, что эти переменные будут иметь разные адреса в памяти: ведь раз области существования не пересекаются, компилятор вправе выделить под них одно и то же место. Хуже того, компилятор вообще имеет право не выделять место под переменную в памяти, а поместить её, например, в регистр, раз программа не запрашивает адрес.

Comment: @VladD Может быть и еще хуже - не помещать даже в регистр, а просто использовать то или иное значение...

Comment: Обратите внимание, что и gcc, и clang, и MSVC генерируют совершенно одинаковый объектный код для функций m1 и m2: https://godbolt.org/z/daYKbMKjq (для MSVC промотайте в самый низ)

Comment: @Harry: В дизассемблированном коде видно, что именно так оно и происходит.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> каждая переменная будет иметь разный адрес

А вот не обязательно. Области жизни этих переменных не пересекаются, т.е. за раз существует не больше одной из них, значит адреса могут совпадать.

> Какие имена им будут присвоены после компиляции

После компиляции имена переменных не хранятся.

Если знаете ассемблер, посмотрите [результат дизассемблирования](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/accTW339x) с оптимизацией и без нее.

Я там увидел вот что:

- Со включенной оптимизацией `a`, `b`, `c` оказались в регистре, причем в одном и том же.
- Со выключенной оптимизацией `a`, `b`, `c` оказались на стеке, в разных местах. Соответственно доступ к ним из ассемблера выглядит как разыменовывание [указателя на stack frame](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80) с каким-то смещением. Здесь у разных переменных смещение оказалось разное, но раз они не живут одновременно, то оно могло бы быть и одинаковое.

Comment: Спасибо, а как компилятор решает, когда отправить объект в регистр, а когда на стек. И я не совсем имею представление о том, что вообще такое регистр, слышал только про регистры, которые участки памяти внутри процессора.

Comment: @n1kzzz *"которые участки памяти внутри процессора"* А это они и есть. Советую для общего развития немного пописать на ассемблере. *"как компилятор решает, когда отправить объект в регистр"* Если очень грубо: Регистры работают быстрее, так что по идее он должен предпочитать регистры. Но их во-первых мало, во-вторых у них нет адресов (если нужно, чтобы адрес был, тогда он не подойдет), в-третьих они могут быть нужны для чего-то другого (например похоже, что вызов `std::cout << int` всегда берет int из конкретного регистра, поэтому что-то другое в нем хранить не получится).

Comment: Это конечно немного не в тему, но все таки не хотелось бы ради этого создавать новый вопрос. А если мы берем функции, хранятся ли их имена в памяти? Просто насколько я знаю функции не являются объектами , как они хранятся в памяти?

Comment: Я попробую выдвинуть предположение, что их имена находятся в некоторой таблице символов, можете меня поправть?

Comment: @n1kzzz В памяти хранится машинный код функций, а указатель на функцию соответственно указывает на ее первую инструкцию. Про таблицу символов сам немного знаю. Имена функций, которые там лежат, можно убрать (в гцц флажком `-s`), так что видимо они там в дебажных целях.

Comment: Я тут немного поразмыслил и заранее извиняюсь за свой вопрос, но что из себя представляет указатель? Как при выполнении программы удается заполучить этот самый адрес, который в себе содержит указатель, он же не статичный, он не известен во время написания кода(если мы его вручную не задаем, но я не про это) и не известен во время компиляции (в некоторых случаях возможно известен но я опять не про это). Что помогает программе его получить?

Comment: Не могли бы вы подсказать где можно почитать про вопросы такого типа, как у меня. Просто с моей стороны это уже неуместно их задавать(

Comment: @n1kzzz Линковщик проставляет эти адреса в коде, но не знаю, как конкретно это происходит. *"где можно почитать про вопросы"* ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Спрашивайте здесь. Но наверное лучше в виде вопросов, а не в комментах.

Comment: Спасибо, пойду задавать вопрос, может кто-то ответит)

Answer (score 6):

Имена переменных — чисто синтаксическая конструкция. В типичном компиляторе имя нужно только на этапе первичного (синтаксического) разбора, а далее вместо имени используется структура данных, описывающая переменную. Поскольку у нас три независимые переменные, то у нас будут три структуры данных, а в той точке, где они используются, будет в той или иной форме ссылка на эту структуру данных.

Далее имя *может* храниться с целью вывода диагностических сообщений, но это будет, разумеется, первоначальное имя, данное пользователем.

Как компилятор отличит их — ну точно так же, как он отличает разные объекты.

Код

```cpp
{
   int a = 1;
   std::cout << a;
}
{
   int a = 2;
   std::cout << a;
}
```

будет преобразован внутри компилятора во что-то такое:

```
operator sequence
  ...
   * assignment
       * target ────────────> [int variable]
       * value ──> const 1      ^
   * function call ─────────────┼──┐
       * arg 1 ─────────────────┼──┼────> [global object of type ostream] <──┐
       * arg 2 ─────────────────┘  │                                         │
   * assignment                    └────────> [function << of ostream type]  │
       * target ────────────> [another int variable]    ^                    │
       * value ──> const 2      ^                       │                    │
   * function call ─────────────┼───────────────────────┘                    │
       * arg 1 ─────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────┘
       * arg 2 ─────────────────┘
  ...
```

Как видите, имена оказались не нужны.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122632/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd-----).

Answer (score 3):

Может быть и еще хуже - вообще никаких переменных, даже в регистре :) - вот что делает VC++ 2019:

```
; 5    :     {
; 6    :        int a = 1;
; 7    :        std::cout << a << std::endl;

    push    1
    mov ecx, OFFSET ?cout@std@@3V?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@A ; std::cout
    call    ??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@H@Z 
    push    eax
```

Comment: gcc и clang делают то же самое: https://godbolt.org/z/daYKbMKjq

Comment: @VladD Ну, в ваших вариантах все же в регистр пишется... Хотя... в моем варианте с тем же успехом вносится в стек :)

Comment: У меня в регистр, а у вас в стек пишется для передачи параметра в `operator <<`, а переменная по сути вообще отсутствует :)

Comment: В 32-bit аргументы передаются в стеке, в 64-bit в регистрах

Comment: @avp: Угу, переменная исчезла, а параметры передаются согласно ABI.